# Show integer value into img tag in mvc 3 razor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display a integer into a img tag, this is my code:

```
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/icons/Circle_White.png")" alt="Alternate Text"       style="position:absolute;" />
    @Html.ActionLink("ViewCommand", "ViewCommand", "Work")
```

[image]

now I want to display my integer into the circle, can someone help me??? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a div for this,

- inside the div show the integer value
- set the background to the image you have at `~/Content/Images/icons/Circle_White.png`

This is one of the way I know